# Combine singular and plural form of 'party'

Tags: word-usage, nouns, plural-forms, singular

Recently I came across following sentence on a form at a client's intranet:

> Enter the domain name(s) of the external party(s) you want to share with.

Except for the fact that the sentence doesn't *sound* 100% correct in my head when I read it, the part that disturbed me most was `party(s)`.

In the case of *name(s)* it's correct as the plural of name is names. But the plural of *party* is *parties* and not *partys*.

My question is: how can you combine the singular and plural of the word party in one 'word'. Or is there another short form to do this?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50885/parenthetical-pluralization-of-words-ending-in-y

Comment: @Alex_ander thanks for pointing that out. I didn't dive deeper into EL&U as I thought this question would be too basic there.

Comment: You could write party(ies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better versions of this include:

> Enter the domain name of **any** external party you want to share with.
>   Enter the domain names of **all** external parties you want to share with.

Either version completely avoids having to come up with an awkward construction that tries to join singular and plural words. Which one you use would be a matter of personal preference.

Comment: This one not only solves the problem, it also *sounds* right, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rewriting the sentence as "Enter the domain name/names of the external party/parties you want to share with."

Answer (score 0):

Since all domain names entered both singular and plural are included in the term it would only be the plural venacular of external parties that would be used. So; Enter the domain name(s) of external parties you wish to include.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).